# Waiting timeout for Firefox [WatiN]

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, timeout, watin

Is there any way of changing the timeout for Firefox using WatiN?

It throws this error: "Timeout while waiting for main document becoming available".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the page is taking longer time to load then you can use

```
Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 480;
```

to increase the wait time before it fires the time out exception.

Or, if the page gets loaded in a variable amount of time for each run, so WaitForCompleteTimeOut time can't be fixed in that scenario, you can search for a text on the page and wait till that text appears, in this manner,

```
ie.WaitUntilContainsText("Any text on the page");
```